# What happens to activity logs related to deleted questions?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions, recent-activity

One or two days ago I posted some comments. Now, I am not able to find them in the activity log (the 'activity' tab on the profile page). I assume that is because the question was deleted.

The [FAQ article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) on deletion does not mention logs.

Are all log entries deleted together with the deletion of the question?

Comment: What activity logs? What log entries? It's unclear what you ask here. Anyway, many comments just get deleted after being flagged, it is not always because their parent post is deleted.

Comment: @Shadow I assume they mean `tab=activity&sort=comments` under their profile where you can see all your comment activity.

Comment: @PeterJ precisely

Comment: @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard I'm not asking about *why a post is deleted*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, almost all activities related to deleted posts are not shown in the profile. The only exception I know of are [Delete votes](/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion) and [Close votes](/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure). This is just my observation, I can't find any reference for this right now.

The 'activity logs' are not actually deleted, since questions or answers aren't physicially deleted from the database. ♦ moderators can always undelete them and authors and high-reputation users can (vote to) undelete them under certain circumstances as well. That would be ... hard ... if the post was really deleted. Comments are kept as well; they will be 'restored' if the post is undeleted and then they will appear on your activity tab as well.

This is implied by the following part of the FAQ:

> #### What does deletion mean for a post?
>
> Deleted posts are usually **not** physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted).

Comment: mentioned? you mean shown? or mentioned in the FAQ?

Comment: That was a reply to your "The FAQ article on deletion does not mention logs."

Comment: ok... I'm a bit confused. Am I not supposed to say "deletion"? I was aware of the fact that they are not *actually* deleted after reading the FAQ.